# Setting a Method to run for a set time?

Tags: java

Im after some help on how to make a method run for 5 minutes then stop, after being called by a boolean function please. I can get the method to run ok but can't seem to set any timer for it that works, the method either runs continuosly when called or not at all. I have searched here and found some suggestions, but no luck so far.

Here is the part of the code where the method is called, subject to boolean condition being met

```
 public void start()
{
    super.start();
    drawing(true);
}

public void msgCollision(Actor actor, String s, String s1)
{
    if(boom)
    {
        t1 = Time.current();
        t2 = Time.current() + 30000L;
        if(t1 < t2)
            MarkTarget();
    } else
    if(!boom)
    {
        Point3d point3d = new Point3d();
        super.pos.getTime(Time.current(), point3d);
        Vector3d vector3d = new Vector3d();
        getSpeed(vector3d);
        vector3d.x = vector3d.y = vector3d.z = 0.0D;
        setSpeed(vector3d);
```

Im new to programming and java, so forgive me if i am missing something obvious, its getting the MarkTarget() method to run for 5 minutes i'm having trouble with, it seems to run continuosly when boolean boom is called with t1 < t2, its as if t2 is never reached, if i change it to t2 < t1 then it doesn't run at all as i would expect.

Is the time being reset every time the code runs? so that 5 minutes is never achieved before the code runs again and Time.current() is therfore moved on? or doesn't it work like that? I want the 5 minutes to be calculated from when boom is initiated.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because you evaluate the value of t1 to that of t2 once right after you instantiate the variables.

```
if(boom)
{
    t1 = Time.current();  //t1 is now the current time
    t2 = Time.current() + 30000L; //t2 is now the current time + 5 minutes
    if(t1 < t2) //Is t1 smaller then t2? Yes it is!
        MarkTarget(); //call the function
    //Anything else? no so we will have had 1 call to it
}
```

You could if you really want to do it this way:

```
if (boom)
{
    t1 = Time.current();
    t2 = t1 + 30000L;
    while (t1 < t2) {
        MarkTarget();
        t1 = Time.current();
    }
}
```

Do realize that with this way, MarkTarget() will be called a lot of times for 5 minutes. If you want it to be called just once and then wait 5 minutes:

```
MarkTarget();
while (t1 < t2) {
    t1 = Time.current();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have initialised t1 and t2 at the same place.
So, `t2=t1+30000L` at any given time

Solution: initialize t1 before u call msgCollision() and instead of `t1<t2`, use this condition `if((Time.current()-t1)<30000L)`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, i thought it may be some way the timing was being declared but couldn't figure out wher i was going wrong,@FlorisVelleman @TwoThe

Answer (score 0):

Well if you call that function continuously, you can write it like this:

```
if(boom) {
  if (timeDone < 0) {
    timeDone = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 5; // now + 5 minutes
  }
  MarkTarget();
  if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= timeDone) { // now >= done-time?
    boom = false;
    timeDone = -1;
  }
} else {
```

Otherwise you might want to have a look into the Timer class or (more sophisticated) the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.